# WPF Data binding issue regarding locator

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, viewmodellocator

this may be a silly question but i can't seem to figure out the problem.

I have a WPF project, I wanted to rename it and went about doing mercurial refactor.

All in all it seems to have done a good job the only problem is my datacontext for the viewmodel seems to be messed up.

An example of one of the pages is like so

```
<Page x:Class="Cirdan.Excite.Views.ViewerPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Cirdan.Excite.Controls"
  xmlns:infrastructure="clr-namespace:Cirdan.Excite.Infrastructure"
  DataContext="{Binding ViewerViewModel, Source={x:Static infrastructure1:MainWindow.LocatorX}}"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  d:DesignHeight="1024" d:DesignWidth="1280"
  Title="Viewer">
```

The error i get is that LocatorX neither exists or is accessible. however I can go to the source of both my ViewModel and where my LocatorX is defined so its aware of them and the LocatorX is public.

This was all working fine before the rename so its linked to it somehow

Comment: Is your MainWindow still defined in Cirdan.Excite.Infrastructure namespace or its namespace were changed?

Comment: Hi, the namespaces where changed also, they are all using the same namespace though

Answer (score 0):

While I understand your issue, it's unclear to what you are actually asking.

These are the steps I would do:

- First do a brute force check.  That is, look at every class and XAML (and any code-behinds) and make sure all instances of `<name-of-item>` are correct.  Also make sure the namespaces used are correct.
- After correcting any wrong values, then *clean* and *rebuild* your project(s).
- If it still gives you an error you can restart visual studio (or the WPF designer).

I've ran into some funny issues here before and once needed to verify that my assemblies are all built to the correct target platforms too.

If you still can't get it working, create a clean project and merge your code back together.